# Error: CS0103 The name 'Me' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am still learning (vb .net), so i tried to make a button that exit the program, once i write the code,

> Me.close();

I get an error saying:

> The name 'Me' does not exist in the current context

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnESC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Me.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is C#, not vb.net. Change the tag to reflect that

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Just noticed :) - HAHHHHA

Comment: C'mon, guys! The question does not deserve to be downvoted to oblivion. Closed maybe, it is from a newbie - yes. Simple - yes. But there is an answer and it is a valid question.

Comment: @trailmax I disagree. There have to be certain rules what make a good question. Knowing which language you're using is certainly one of them.

Comment: @trailmax "does not show any research effort". This is exactly that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto to do research you need to know where to start. Given this exception alone and not having any background in programming it'll be hard to figure out where to start searching for answers.

Comment: @trailmax So now we teach how to use Google? Didn't know that... Just Google "vb.net me" and the answer is the first or second link, c'mmon

Comment: Guys don't be angry .. 
This is my first language ..
And btw this is a way of researches !!!

Comment: `this is a way of researches` I have to disagree, there is a difference between ***research and neglect***... Research requires investigation and study to help establish facts, ***NOT*** asking someone else to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're writing C#, not VB.

VB.NET uses `Me` as a reference to the current instance.

C# uses `this`

Comment: Oh .. THANKS ALOT 

But how I can change to VB, cuz I watching a tut and this is what he did ?

And for the code DIM, what I should use ?
Cuz I have same problem with it !

Comment: You have to create a VB.NET project, if you want to code in VB.NET.